# .htaccess redirect false subfolder to actual subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Folder structure on the server is: /var/www/domain.com/secure/files..

I would like to rename "secure" to "admin" in the URL but still have it pull files from /secure/.

So, http://domain.com/admin/ pulls from what the actual folder is called on the server, "secure".

Below is what I currently have in .htaccess.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) scp/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

The above works if you type in http://domain.com/admin/ (Would like it to add the trailing slash if left off); but also allows http://domain.com/scp/ (it does not redirect to admin like I want, also adds the trailing slash if left off).

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /scp(\S*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302,NE]

    RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ scp$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```